# I want to change my permalink structure

Tags: permalinks

I am looking to update my permalink structure by adding a category and date in the UR to make it more feasible for users to understand the post category and published date. Can you please guide me on this? Currently, my URL shows in this format, https://thestumbleguys.com/download-kipas-guys/

Answer (score 0):

For having the `/year/month/date/category/post-name` you should edit the Permalink from Settings and choose "Custom Structure" and enter `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%category%/%postname%/` value and save it.

[image]